# GoogleMap API Gives Wrong Coordinates for Direction between two Points

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios, ios6.1, ios6-maps

I am using GoogleMap API for showing draw direction between two points on GoogleMap.

i want to give support on iOS 6.1 so i use GoogleMap i know about iOS7 recover this.

using below code for parsing and get Steps for coordinates to draw polyline on Map:

```
NSString *str=@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=bharuch,gujarat&destination=vadodara,gujarat&sensor=false";

NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
     NSError* error;

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray* latestRoutes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];

NSMutableDictionary *legs=[[[latestRoutes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *steps=[legs objectForKey:@"steps"];

NSString *startLocation,*endLocation,*totalDistance,*totalDuration;
     CLLocationCoordinate2D startLoc,endLoc;
     startLocation = [legs  objectForKey:@"start_address"];
     endLocation = [legs objectForKey:@"end_address"];
     totalDistance = [[legs objectForKey:@"distance"] objectForKey:@"text"];
     totalDuration = [[legs objectForKey:@"duration"] objectForKey:@"text"];
     startLoc=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[legs objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[legs objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);
     endLoc=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[legs objectForKey:@"end_location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[legs objectForKey:@"end_location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);

     NSMutableDictionary *tempDict;
     if ([steps count]!=0) {
         GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
         for(int idx = 0; idx < [steps count]+2; idx++){

            CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;

            if (idx==0) {

                workingCoordinate=startLoc;

                [path addCoordinate:workingCoordinate];

            }
            else if (idx==[steps count]+1){

                workingCoordinate=endLoc;

                [path addCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
            }
            else{

                workingCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[[steps objectAtIndex:idx-1] objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue], [[[[steps objectAtIndex:idx-1] objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] floatValue]);

                [path addCoordinate:workingCoordinate];

            }
            tempDict = nil;
        }
        // create the polyline based on the array of points.

        GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];

        rectangle.strokeWidth=5.0;

        rectangle.map = mapView_;
    }
```

its gives only 24 steps means only 24 Coordinates for create point and draw Line on Map which is shown as below image:

[image: after drawing line on map and zoom to few level]

you can see that line is not on proper road so what can i do to solve this?
i also want to show direction on map too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below answer is for smooth path between two location with help of @A Báo:

> ```
> -(void)viewDidLoad {
>
>     // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
>
>     GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:21.718472 longitude:73.030422 zoom:6];
>     mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
>     mapView_.delegate=self;
>     mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
>     mapView_.settings.myLocationButton=YES;
>     mapView_.settings.indoorPicker=NO;
>     mapView_.settings.compassButton=YES;
>
>     self.view = mapView_;
>
>     NSString *str=@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Bharuch,gujarat&destination=vadodara,gujarat&sensor=false";
>
>     NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
>
>     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
>
>     NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
>
>     NSError* error;
>     NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
>
>     NSArray* latestRoutes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
>
>     NSString *points=[[[latestRoutes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];
>
>     @try {
>         // TODO: better parsing. Regular expression?
>
>         NSArray *temp= [self decodePolyLine:[points mutableCopy]];
>
>         GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
>
>         for(int idx = 0; idx < [temp count]; idx++)
>         {
>            CLLocation *location=[temp objectAtIndex:idx];
>
>             [path addCoordinate:location.coordinate];
>
>         }
>         // create the polyline based on the array of points.
>
>         GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
>
>         rectangle.strokeWidth=5.0;
>
>         rectangle.map = mapView_;
>
>     }
>     @catch (NSException * e) {
>         // TODO: show error
>     }
> }
>
> -(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded {
>   [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
>                               options:NSLiteralSearch
>                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
>   NSInteger len = [encoded length];
>   NSInteger index = 0;
>   NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
>   NSInteger lat=0;
>   NSInteger lng=0;
>   while (index < len) {
>       NSInteger b;
>       NSInteger shift = 0;
>       NSInteger result = 0;
>       do {
>           b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
>           result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
>           shift += 5;
>       } while (b >= 0x20);
>       NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
>       lat += dlat;
>       shift = 0;
>       result = 0;
>       do {
>           b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
>           result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
>           shift += 5;
>       } while (b >= 0x20);
>       NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
>       lng += dlng;
>       NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] ;
>       NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] ;
>       printf("[%f,", [latitude doubleValue]);
>       printf("%f]", [longitude doubleValue]);
>       CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] ;
>       [array addObject:loc];
>   }
>
>   return array;
> }
> ```

Screenshot of this code you can compare it with previous screenshot which i used in asking Question:
[image]

Comment: in some case  app crashed in decodePolyLine method at characterAtIndex

 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

if in while loop of  decodePolyLine method i changes the  while (index < len) to while (index < len-2 ) it doesn't crash   @jayraj m.g.

Comment: i add this code in my app but map is not appear in my app

Answer (score 1):

I did add GMSMarker to each point get on steps array and I sure that use steps array start_location and end_location not enough to show direction in your map. here is code I did edit from your code

```
NSString *str=@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=bharuch,gujarat&destination=vadodara,gujarat&sensor=false";

NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSError *error;

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

NSArray* latestRoutes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];

NSMutableDictionary *legs=[[[latestRoutes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *steps=[legs objectForKey:@"steps"];

NSString *startLocation,*endLocation,*totalDistance,*totalDuration;

CLLocationCoordinate2D startLoc,endLoc;

startLocation = [legs objectForKey:@"start_address"];

endLocation = [legs objectForKey:@"end_address"];

totalDistance = [[legs objectForKey:@"distance"] objectForKey:@"text"];

totalDuration = [[legs objectForKey:@"duration"] objectForKey:@"text"];

startLoc=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[legs objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[legs objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);

NSMutableDictionary *stopLegs=[[[latestRoutes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"legs"] objectAtIndex:0];
endLoc=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[stopLegs objectForKey:@"end_location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue], [[[stopLegs objectForKey:@"end_location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue]);

NSMutableDictionary *tempDict;

if ([steps count]!=0) {
    // add marker
    NSDictionary *step;
    for (int i= 0; i < steps.count; i++) {
        step = [steps objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary *location = [step objectForKey:@"start_location"];
        double lat = [[location objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        double lng = [[location objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);
        marker.snippet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"point (%d)", i+1];
        marker.map = mapView_;
    }
    NSDictionary *location = [step objectForKey:@"end_location"];
    double lat = [[location objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
    double lng = [[location objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng);
    marker.snippet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"point (%d)", steps.count];
    marker.map = mapView_;

    // continue draw map
    GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];

    for(int idx = 0; idx < [steps count]+2; idx++){

        CLLocationCoordinate2D workingCoordinate;

        if (idx==0) {

            workingCoordinate=startLoc;

            [path addCoordinate:workingCoordinate];

        }
        else if (idx==[steps count]+1){

            workingCoordinate=endLoc;

            [path addCoordinate:workingCoordinate];
        }
        else{

            workingCoordinate=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[[steps objectAtIndex:idx-1] objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lat"] floatValue], [[[[steps objectAtIndex:idx-1] objectForKey:@"start_location"] objectForKey:@"lng"] floatValue]);

            [path addCoordinate:workingCoordinate];

        }
        tempDict = nil;
    }
    // create the polyline based on the array of points.

    GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];

    rectangle.strokeWidth=5.0;

    rectangle.map = mapView_;
}
```

you can see betwen point 12 and point 13 have a big distance (60.2 km). but it just one path. I did find out that if you want to show approximate (smoothed) path of the resulting directions. you need use "overview_polyline" field. overview_polyline: contains an object holding an array of encoded points that represent an approximate (smoothed) path of the resulting directions. this [link google map develop](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en#TravelModes) helpful for you. So work for you is find method to decode data from "overview_polyline" to get correct path between two point. I definitely it's true way to resolve your problem because I did check tool to decode "overview_polyline" at [Encoded Polyline Algorithm Format](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylineutility)
This Image what I got from decode:
[image: decode Polyline]

To decode polyne string you can find at this block http://objc.id.au/post/9245961184/mapkit-encoded-polylines

- Continue, with code from @jayraj m.g. Below answer is for smooth path between two location

> ```
> -(void)viewDidLoad {
>
>     // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
>
>     GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:21.718472 longitude:73.030422 zoom:6];
>     mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
>     mapView_.delegate=self;
>     mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
>     mapView_.settings.myLocationButton=YES;
>     mapView_.settings.indoorPicker=NO;
>     mapView_.settings.compassButton=YES;
>
>     self.view = mapView_;
>
>     NSString *str=@"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=Bharuch,gujarat&destination=vadodara,gujarat&sensor=false";
>
>     NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:[str stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
>
>     NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
>
>     NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
>
>     NSError* error;
>     NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
>
>     NSArray* latestRoutes = [json objectForKey:@"routes"];
>
>     NSString *points=[[[latestRoutes objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"overview_polyline"] objectForKey:@"points"];
>
>     @try {
>         // TODO: better parsing. Regular expression?
>
>         NSArray *temp= [self decodePolyLine:[points mutableCopy]];
>
>         GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];
>
>         for(int idx = 0; idx < [temp count]; idx++)
>         {
>            CLLocation *location=[temp objectAtIndex:idx];
>
>             [path addCoordinate:location.coordinate];
>
>         }
>         // create the polyline based on the array of points.
>
>         GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
>
>         rectangle.strokeWidth=5.0;
>
>         rectangle.map = mapView_;
>
>     }
>     @catch (NSException * e) {
>         // TODO: show error
>     }
> }
>
> -(NSMutableArray *)decodePolyLine: (NSMutableString *)encoded {
>   [encoded replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"
>                               options:NSLiteralSearch
>                                 range:NSMakeRange(0, [encoded length])];
>   NSInteger len = [encoded length];
>   NSInteger index = 0;
>   NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
>   NSInteger lat=0;
>   NSInteger lng=0;
>   while (index < len) {
>       NSInteger b;
>       NSInteger shift = 0;
>       NSInteger result = 0;
>       do {
>           b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
>           result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
>           shift += 5;
>       } while (b >= 0x20);
>       NSInteger dlat = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
>       lat += dlat;
>       shift = 0;
>       result = 0;
>       do {
>           b = [encoded characterAtIndex:index++] - 63;
>           result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
>           shift += 5;
>       } while (b >= 0x20);
>       NSInteger dlng = ((result & 1) ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
>       lng += dlng;
>       NSNumber *latitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lat * 1e-5] ;
>       NSNumber *longitude = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:lng * 1e-5] ;
>       printf("[%f,", [latitude doubleValue]);
>       printf("%f]", [longitude doubleValue]);
>       CLLocation *loc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:[latitude floatValue] longitude:[longitude floatValue]] ;
>       [array addObject:loc];
>   }
>
>   return array;
> }
> ```

Screenshot of this code you can compare it with previous screenshot which i used in asking Question:
[image]

Thanks @jayraj m.g.

Comment: check my edited code section in question for what i am using to draw line and what google api gives me

Comment: @jayrajm.g. I very interesting with your question and I did find out to resolve it. I hope you will happy with this answer I did edid

Comment: @A Báo : what a coincidence i tried same 'overview_polyline' for getting all correct path and it gives smooth path. thank for giving interest in my quetion and i will accept your answer if you updated your answer with 'Overview_Polyline' because right now this answer not showing smoothline..

Comment: @jayrajm.g. I did edit the answer, it's very clearly for any one who concerned with this problem. Thanks from your code :)

Comment: @jayrajm.g. can we set the camera postion according to user current location