# Draw route on google application ios sdk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I want to draw route from current location to the destination location.

I am using the following code.

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"comgooglemaps://"]]) {
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"comgooglemaps://?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%@,%@&directionsmode=driving",
                               appDelegate.myLocation.coordinate.latitude,
                               appDelegate.myLocation.coordinate.longitude,
                               self.objPlace.strLatitude,
                               self.objPlace.strLongitude];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlString]];
    }
```

**Result Image**           ---------------------------------- **Expected Image**

[image: Result Image]                                  [image]

```
comgooglemaps://?saddr=23.033646,72.559139&daddr=23.033018,72.557025&directionsmode=driving
```

**NOTE : I am asking for native google application not within the application**

But it is not showing route?

Answer (score 0):

I did answer this question in other topic. Please check this topic at link [GoogleMap API Gives Wrong Coordinates for Direction between two Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22091271/googlemap-api-gives-wrong-coordinates-for-direction-between-two-points/22093166?noredirect=1#comment33592236_22093166)

Comment: i am not asking for routing within application. i want to draw route in  build google maps application

Comment: Yes but it open in safari

Comment: when your device install googlemap app, use this link 'http://maps.google.com/maps?' will open map app, but if u use device not have map app or simulator it will open in safari